How can I adjust an image view to make sure an image fills the bounds but does not crop
Lets say I have an image view and I want to display a 600 x 900 image. I want to make sure the image fills the image view, but it not cropping "center crop" or using "scaleXY". After that, how can I make sure it works for different phone sizes.
Also, are there libraries that handle this?
I want to use something like this, so my image view fits nicely in my layout
<ConstraintLayout >     
<ImageView         
android:layout_width="0dp"         
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</ConstraintLayout>


You can set imageView height and width according to your requirements like this:
android:layout_width="600dp"
android:layout_height="900dp"

And set its scale type to fitXY, like this
android:scaleType="fitXY"

This will ensure that your image is filling the imageView
